# Amazon S3 cache audio files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created new music application and I store all mp3 files on Amazon S3. Before moving to S3 I used store them on server file system itself. It used to cache files and on consecutive reload of page files weren't downloaded from server. But after moving to S3 everytime I load page it downloads files from S3. This not only making my app slow but every request to S3 is money.
I found some documentation on cache-control and I tried them all but no success. I might be missing something here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my code for uploading mp3 files on S3. I use CarrierWave with Rails.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
      :provider               => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id      =>  MyAppConfig.config['aws']['aws_access_key'],
      :aws_secret_access_key  => MyAppConfig.config['aws']['aws_secret_key'],
    }
    config.fog_directory  = MyAppConfig.config['aws']['aws_bucket_name']
    config.fog_public     = false
    config.storage = :fog
    config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

Comment: "it" downloads files from S3... what is "it?"  The browser? Or the server?  Are you trying to use S3 as a filesystem?

Comment: Are you using signed URLs?

Comment: not sure but I think yes, url has some key_id & expiry date.

Comment: That may be the key to the problem.  I can't put my finger on an authoritative source to cite at the moment, but experience tells me that (some|all) browsers (usually|always) ignore their local cache whenever there's a query string in the URL; that is, a `?` in the URL will prevent the browser from using its local cache, and instead always try to fetch the resource again.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, that might be the case. What should be the ideal way of handling such scenario. I mean there should be some way for me to reduce my requests to S3. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using signed URLs, which you say you are in the comments, *and not reusing those signed URLs* then there is no way to cache these requests.

Amazon Web Services cannot override your Web browser's internal cache system. When two URIs are unique, as they are with signed URLs, then your Web browser treats them as two distinct resources on the Internet.

For example, let's take:

```
http://www.example.com/song1.mp3
http://www.example.com/song2.mp3
```

These are two discrete URIs. Even if `song1.mp3` and `song2.mp3` had the same `Etag` and `Content-Length` HTTP response headers, they're still two different resources.

The same is true if we merely alter their query strings:

```
http://www.example.com/song1.mp3?a=1&b=2&c=3
http://www.example.com/song1.mp3?a=1&b=2&c=4
```

These are *still* two discrete URIs. They will not reference one another for purposes of caching. This is the principle behind using [query strings to override caching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=query+string+caching).

No amount of fiddling with HTTP headers will ever get you the cache behavior you're seeking.

Comment: If you can help me understanding signed url vs unsigned url, then probably I will be able decide on whether I can go for unsigned url which as per you should solve my problem.

Comment: AWS signed URLs look like `/song1.mp3?Expires=123&Signature=abc` and are generated on demand. If you're creating signed URLs for each request, then those are not being cached by anyone. You have two options to cache the object: 1) make the object's read policy `public` so everyone can access it via `/song1.mp3` without the query string, 2) create a system to store and manage the signed URLs so that the same user sees the same exact signed URL `/song1.mp3?Expires=123&Signature=abc` multiple times (a much larger job).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-set-cache-control-header-for-s3-object.html

Set Cache-Control for already uploaded file on S3 using Update Metadata:

1) Run Bucket Explorer and login with your credentials.

2) After listing all Buckets, select any S3 Bucket.

3) It will list all objects of selected S3 Bucket.

4) Select any file and right click on the objects and select “Update Metadata” option.

5) Add Key and Value in Metadata attributes. Enter Key: “Cache-Control” with Value: “max-age = (time for which you want your object to be accessed from cache in seconds)”

6) Click on Save button. It will update metadata as Cache-Control on all selected S3 objects.

```
Example to set max-age: For time limit of 15 days = 3600 * 24 * 15 = 1296000 sec. Set Key = “Cache-Control” value = “max-age=1296000”
```

**Note:** If object is HTML file, set Key: “Cache-Control” and value: max-age = (time for which you want your object to be accessed from cache in seconds), must-revalidate “i.e. Key: “Cache-Control” value: max-age = “2592000, must re-validate” for 30 days. “must re-validate” string must be added after the time in second as value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have properly set the cache control headers and you are using signed URL's than you will need to hold onto the signed URL for a given file and re-render the exact same URL in subsequent page loads.

If you have not set the cache control headers or you want them to change based on who is making the request you can set them before signing your URL with: `&response-cache-control=value` or `&response-expires=value`.